# INSERT INTO - doesn't have default value

Tags: mysql

Intention: I want to INSERT -  COLUMN -> 'b.pe_loglogins_name' from TABLE -> pe_loglogins and add it to the TABLE -> pe_LogEvent in COLUMN -> pe_LogEvent_pilotid

I am struggling to get past this error, I'm not quite sure how to resolve it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*"Error updating record: Field 'LogEvent_type' doesn't have a default value"*

```
ALTER TABLE pe_logevent ADD IF NOT EXISTS `pe_LogEvent_pilotid` BIGINT(20) NULL

INSERT INTO pe_LogEvent(pe_LogEvent_pilotid) 
SELECT b.pe_loglogins_playerid
FROM pe_LogEvent AS a
INNER JOIN pe_loglogins AS b ON a.pe_LogEvent_PilotName = b.pe_LogLogins_name
WHERE a.pe_LogEvent_PilotName IS NOT NULL AND b.pe_LogLogins_name = a.pe_LogEvent_PilotName
GROUP BY a.pe_LogEvent_PilotName
```

[image: Visual representation of exactly what I am attempting to accomplish.]

Here is the SQL DB File If Needed to try out yourself: https://www.mediafire.com/file/61sg953aaaoijqj/wtfstats_%25281%2529.sql/file

Comment: "_Error updating record: Field 'LogEvent_type' doesn't have a default value_" Sure that's the correct file/code you're showing? `LogEvent_type` doesn't seem to appear _anywhere_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message arises from the `INSERT` which will create new rows, when you actually want to `UPDATE` existing rows.

So, using your database dump on my server I ran this query:

```
update pe_logevent set 
   pe_LogEvent_pilotid = (
        select distinct pe_LogLogins_playerid from pe_loglogins 
            where pe_LogLogins_Name = pe_LogEvent_pilotname
   );
```

It took about half a second to run.

Here's an excerpt of the result (some columns omitted for brevity):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If `pe_LogEvent_pilotid` is supposed to be an auto increment value then it’s not specified in the add.

Comment: pe_LogEvent_pilotid is not supposed to be an auto increment value.
It's supposed to be updated by the values from the pe_loglogins_playerid column.